# Disable collapsing animation in bootstrap on "close" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I have made some collapsing panels with bootstrap. Then added a method to "close" and remove the panels using angular. Only problem is that when I close the panel, the collapsing, open/close functionality still works. So the panel might open and then disappear, when it really should just disappear.

Here is a simplified version of the HTML

```
    <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-info fadein fadeout" ng-repeat="p in panels">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test_{{p}}" style="cursor:pointer">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                open / close - {{p}}
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" ng-click="close(p)"></span>
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="test_{{p}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="panel-body">
                hello {{p}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and angularJS

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('controller', function($scope){

    var i = 4;

    $scope.panels = ['panel_1', 'panel_2', 'panel_3']

    $scope.add = function(){
        console.log('add');
      $scope.panels.push('panel_' + i++);
    }

    $scope.close = function (p) {

        console.log('close ' + p);

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.panels.length; i++){
                if ($scope.panels[i] == p){
                    $scope.panels.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        }
});
```

Made a fiddle to illustrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlejan/82bmcyt0/

When you click on close, the cross on the right. The panel will "open", then disappear (the fadeOut animation does not seem to work here). I would like the close button to just remove the panel when you click close. Not "open" or "close" the panel.

So in case of clicking the close button, the panels collapsing, opening/close function should be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the event object to your ng-click definition:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" ng-click="close(p, $event)"></span>
```

And use that object in your event handler:

```
    $scope.close = function (p, e) {

            console.log('close ' + p);


        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.panels.length; i++){
            if ($scope.panels[i] == p){
                $scope.panels.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    e.stopPropagation();

    }
```